# how to take value from textbox in selenium and call it (textbox contains URL)

Tags: selenium

```
<html>
  <body>
   <form action="demo_form.asp">
     URL: <input type="txtURL" name="URL"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to call the URL stored in textbox and run that URL

Code I have used is  :

```
String XYZ = driver.findElement(By.id("txtURL")).getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: Your code does not match the example HTML. This will never work!

Comment: Divide and conquer: Get the URL from the text box. Then open it. Both are really basic things in Selenium...

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code you provided, the input control does not have an id, use By.name(). Moreover, if you want to get the content of a HTML input, use the "value" attribute:

```
String XYZ = driver.findElement(By.name("URL")).getAttribute("value")
```

Then you can use the get() method to call the URL:

```
driver.get(XYZ)
```

Comment: Thank you sir , but i have tried this and this has not worked for me , is it because of the submit button in my html code.......??

Comment: @user3724559 Check the type of the HTML input, it should be type="text" or type="url", not type="txtURL". To make sure everything works, try pre-filling the HTML input with a test url value: `<input type="text" name="URL" value="http://www.google.com">`

Answer (score 0):

Use driver Navigate GoToUrl method :

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(XYZ);
```

But there is an error getting text box value, you should use something like this:

```
string XYZ = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtURL")).Text;
```